# Azure cli command error while trying to add roles

Tags: azure

tried this command in yml script:

az ad app update --id e042ec79-34cd-498f-9d9f-123456781234 --app-roles @manifest.json

but ended up with below error :

The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression. '@manifest' can be used only as an argument to a command. To reference variables in an expression use '$manifest'.

Comment: From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively#using-quotation-marks-in-values) "There are special characters of PowerShell, such as at @. To run Azure CLI in PowerShell, add ` before the special character to escape it. Instead, you can enclose the value in single or double quotes "/"." Does this help?

Comment: tried giving like this "@manifest.json" but got the below error: 
ERROR: Failed to parse JSON: @manifest.json
Error detail: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Ok, well that suggests that the command is now being understood and the content of the file is wrong in some way.

Comment: what is in the manifest.json?

Comment: this is the $json:
{
    "allowedMemberTypes":  ["Application"],
    "description":  "test role",
    "displayName":  "test.read",
    "isEnabled":  true,
    "value":  testService.Read"
}

and the command from powershell is:
az ad app update --id e042ec79-34cd-498f-9d9f-123456781234 --app-roles $json

Error:
Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: Why have you changed the filename and the command syntax from @manifest.json?